# VbA Worksheet_Change doesnt recognize DELETE key on cell

Tags: excel, vba, onchange, worksheet-function

simple thing:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C1")) Then
        debug.print "value changed"
        If IsEmpty(Target.Value2) Then
            debug.print "ie empty"
        else
            debug.print "is not empty"
        end if
    end if
end sub
```

I have added the:

```
debug.print "value changed"
```

to see if the "delete" key is triggering the Worksheet_Change() and it does NOT, it is triggered only on changing the value (or add if was empty)! But once there is something, and I select the cell and press DELETE on keyboard, nothing happens :(

what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
If Intersect(Target, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C1")) Then
```

with:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1")) Is Nothing Then
```

**EDIT#1:**

One possible  issue is that `If` expects a `Boolean` and `Intersect()` is returning a `Range`.  Excel is trying to interpret the `Range` and succeeds some of the time.

Comment: Hello, it works... can you elaborate? i dont see the real logical difference between your code and mine

Comment: @JiriZaloudek  See my **EDIT#1:**

Comment: Hello, actually its not, I have used code "If Not Intersect(Target, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("C1")) Is Nothing Then" and it works fine when i use NOT () IS NOTHING then im allgood, but if i dont do it, then no... so this is what i dont understand

Comment: @JiriZaloudek  I can't answer your question.............at least we found something that works....................I suggest you experiment with variations to discover the root cause of the problem.................